# How long did it take for Earth's magnetic field to first appear?

Tags: geophysics, earth-history, geomagnetism

Merely what the title states. My knowledge of geography/geology/*logy is limited to high-school, and some snippets, and snatches of conversation.

As I understand Earth's magnetic field is attributed to the bi-layered nature of it's core. Proto-Earth probably did not have a magnetic field. Apparently much later Earth's core cooled enough to separate into two layers - causing the field to appear

How long did it take for Earth's magnetic field to first appear? 
As a corollary, did water appear first on Earth, OR did the magnetic field appear first?

Answer (score 10):

The age of the [Earth's magnetic field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) could be as old as the existence of the physical conditions capable of generating a magnetic field. Because we believe the geomagnetic field originates from the liquid outer core, your question could be restated as: When did the Earth form a liquid core?

How the Earth's core formed is still not well understood and the area of research is referred to as [planetary differentiation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CGUQFjAN&url=http%3A%2F%2Fastro.berkeley.edu%2F~gmarcy%2Fastro160%2Fpapers%2FFormation_of_rocky_planets.pdf&ei=gXnhU6uNM4PooAS0zIC4Dg&usg=AFQjCNGVJ2yeuS7ejUCfKbOY4-mqRIWFnw).